# Warrior is not abstract and does not override abstract method getName() in Hero

Tags: java

```
public interface BattleReady{
    abstract int getHealth();
    abstract String getName();
}
```

```
public abstract class Hero implements BattleReady{
  private int health;
  private int level;
  private int experience;
  private int maxHealth;
  private double nextLevelExperience;
  private Inventory inventory;

  public Hero() {
    health = 100;
    maxHealth = 100;
    level = 1;
    nextLevelExperience = 100;
    inventory = new Inventory();  
  }

  public Hero(int health, int level, int experience, int maxHealth,int nextLevelExperience, Inventory inventory){
    this.health = health;
    this.level = level;
    this.experience = experience;
    this.maxHealth = maxHealth;
    this.inventory = inventory;
    this.nextLevelExperience = nextLevelExperience;
  }

  public boolean takeDamage(int amount)
    {
      health = health - amount;
      if(health <= 0)
      {
        health = 0;
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

  public int getLevel() { return level; }
  public int getHealth() { return health; }
  public void setHealth(int health) { this.health = health; }
  public int getExperience() { return experience; }
  public double getNextLevelExperience() { return nextLevelExperience; }

  public void setExperience(int experience) { this.experience = experience; }
  public int getMaxHealth() { return maxHealth; }
  public void setMaxHealth(int maxHealth) { this.maxHealth = maxHealth; }
  public Inventory getInventory() { return inventory; }

  public abstract void display();
  public abstract void upgradeStats();         

  public void incrementLevel() 
  {
    double nextLevel = this.getNextLevelExperience();
    nextLevel += getNextLevelExperience();
    level += 1;
    upgradeStats();
    System.out.println("Hero has leveled up!");
  }   

  public int attack(){
    return (int)(Math.random()*level);
  }

  public abstract String getName();
}
```

```
public class Warrior extends Hero {
  public Warrior() {
    super();
  }
  public  Warrior(int health, int level, int experience, int maxHealth) {

  }

  public void upgradeStats() {
    int h = this.getHealth();
    h += this.getLevel()*12;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "Warrior";
  }
}
```

I need help with this erro.

I'm getting this error when compiled.

> Warrior.java:1: error: Warrior is not abstract and does not override abstract method getName() in Hero
> public class Warrior extends Hero

**Requirement: getName() - It required to return if "Warrior is a hero" (Should this be an abstract method or not in Hero class?)**

Comment: Well, at some point in your class hierarchy you will have to implement the method getName and code its logic. When you declare a method as abstract you are pretty much telling the java compiler "I will provide the implementation in the subclasses". So when you don't provide that implementation in your Warrior subclass the java compiler tells you that this is not valid.

Comment: As to whether the method should be "abstract method or not in Hero class", that is totally dependent on your class design. Both are valid.

Comment: If the names for all Hero subclasses are treated the same, then getName() should probably be defined in Hero. If each subclass has something unique about the name, then maybe it should be in the subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Your getting this error, because your `getName()` Method is abstract - you have to override it in the `Warrior`-Class like this:

```java
@Override
public String getName() {
  return null;
}
```

Don´t forget to do the same thing for the `display()`-Method.

I would recommend annotating overriden methods with `@Override` for clarity. IDEs like IntelliJ can do that for you automatically.